# Cocoa pods interdependent dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, rubygems, cocoapods, podspec

I noticed while looking into my CI logs that one framework is compiled two times and after digging into the issue I noticed one dependency of the main project is also part of another pod dependency

[image]

Now I am looking into ways to make sure dependency(A) only compiles 1 time only
What could be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove pod A as POD B has the POD A dependency you can still access POD A library. We usually add our pod configuration when there is a mismatch of the version with our iOS Version or we want a specific version for our app and other pod dependency has different version, In that case we add our pod configuration for specific library with version.

For example In one my project there was a submodule which was also using the pod GoogleMLkit. But due to of limitation of iOS Version there was a compile time issue in order to use the same google library. At that time i had to enter pod in my main project with the version that i needed that is compaitable with my project.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the dependency of your pod you have to move to pod folder and search *.podspec file in this file you would have something like this.

s.dependency 'packageName', '~> version'